# Visual Studio 2019 Azure Debugging - Remote Debug

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging

I have an Outlook Web Add-in that's hosted in Azure. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and can't debug the app. I have tried the below:
1. Install the Visual Studio Remote tool
2. Tried to "Attach Debugger" to my Azure Web App from VS using "View.Could Explorer" and selecting the Web App; it doesn't work; it's stuck in Processing of attaching the debugger; I waited for over 30 minutes and it still stuck.
3. I have set the Configuration to Debug in the Project Properties

I think it's simple enough - just trying to debug my app that's deployed in Azure. This is a Outlook Web Add-in using JS and Controllers; remote debug is not working in Visual Studio 2019

This does not relate to code - it's the debug process

I should be able to debug my Outlook Web Add-in that is deployed to Azure. I would like to debug JS and Controller code.

Comment: Alternatively, please check this http://toddbaginski.com/blog/how-to-debug-office-add-in-in-office-clients-without-visual-studio/

Comment: Two questions: Which version of VS2019 are you on? Does this happen with other Apps too?

Comment: Hi, I am on Enterprise - debug is working for other Apps (windows/web apps). The app with the issue uses Javascript and it's an Outlook Add-in with the code on Azure.

Comment: Thanks Mohit - I review the link you provide, but haven't had the time to read through - will do that this weekend.

Comment: Hi @Creoabraham, is the link provided by Mohit useful to your problem ? If it helps your problem, could you please put it to the answer area.

Comment: Thanks Mohit - the link seems to provide info on the question,  I will take a look at it later - had to jump on another project.